# Why are firemonkey units added to my DPK when compiling

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe2

Firemonkey units are added to my DPK when compiling under Delphi XE 2, why?

It gives me lots of warnings like this (all related to FMX):

[DCC Warning] W1033 Unit 'FMX.Video' implicitly imported into package. ...

Comment: You just open the project in XE2 and it converts it. Are you saying that at that point in time the FMX units are added to your .dpr file?

Comment: Can you tell witch FMX units were added?

Comment: Can you be very precise. At what stage exactly do the units get added? Which units are added? Can you give instructions for us to reproduce?

Comment: No firemonkey UNITS are added to your DPR file, however some XE2 "unit scope name" aliases will be added to your DPROJ file, so that your existing XE .pas files can continue to be compiled in XE2 without changes.

Comment: unless you can supply detail it's very difficult to help

Comment: Please, just mark your own answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I unchecked the FMX packages in project's options and the message went away.

Answer (score 1):

As David comment, you just open it with Delphi XE2 and it will be converted automatically.

AFAIK, it doesn't added FMX units automatically, but you may confused with new [Unit Scope Names](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Unit_Scope_Names)

Comment: the documentation says "With one notable exception, legacy code should continue to work without changes"